# Excel copy-paste including hidden columns

Tags: excel

I'm using a Excel 2016 worksheet that has a couple of columns hidden for UI reasons. I need to be able to filter out data and then copy-paste it to another sheet with hidden columns intact and showing after pasting in the destination (it will contain a longer log of similar transactions, not just one copy-paste).

Adding a pic of the objective - i.e. hoping to have the hidden contents of columns B and C being pasted into the destination spreadsheet. **Is this possible at all?**

[image]

Probably not great form to ask 2 questions in one post, however are there alternatives to performing filtering and copy-paste function to another spreadsheet manually? I.e.:

- run manual filter to clear blanks in Quantity field;
- make a selection
- do manual Ctrl+C - Ctrl+V function

Is there a way to make it easier? Unfortunately no VBA or macro experience **as of yet**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot do this with regular Excel features since Excel cannot know which columns/cells to skip when one of the column have blank values, this is something has to be decided and done by a human.

Maybe this is a good time to enter the world of Macros, since you do not need a custom code but can use the recorded macro without any further manipulation. This Excel feature is for inexperienced users just like you.

- **View / Macros / Record Macro**
- Name your macro

Do what you need to, keeping in mind that Excel is recording your every move by converting them into VBA codes in the background. For your case, do the following:

- Filter the blanks using filter combo-box
- Select the range by using `CTRL-G` / Special / Current Region (do not select the cells by mouse or with your keyboard, your code should be generic should not contain manual ranges since you do not want to do any coding)
- `CTRL-C` to copy
- If "to-be-pasted" cell is not fixed for all your cases, then you should stop recording your macro here. If pasting cell is fixed then Paste the contents while the macro is recording.

After the macro is recorded, assign a shortcut to your new Macro using:
**Macros / View Macros / Options** menu

Voila! Now you are able to do exactly what you have done when recording your macro by using that keyboard shortcut. If you did not paste the content when recording then you s/b using your macro short cut and go to the cell you want to paste and press `CTRL-V`.

When you feel confident enough, try the **Edit** menu in the **Macros** and see what code you have in hand, maybe make some small changes etc. I saw many people who are not familiar with basic coding at the beginning but somehow started writing their own codes after seeing this feature in Excel. Good Luck!

Answer (score 3):

Edit - Completely misunderstood the question!

You want to include hidden cells when you copy - that's standard behavior for hidden cells but not for filtered columns.  If you want to avoid VBA abd you're dealing with small contiguous ranges then a simple formula may be the easiest solution.

Using your example, I will arbitrarily name the source worksheet "Sheet1" and the destination "Sheet2". In Sheet2, click in cell A2 and type this into the formula bar:   =Sheet1!A3    Now click the bottom right corner of cell A2 and drag it to the right through D2 then down to D7.
With the range highlighted, press ctrl C to copy, then right click to paste special values.

You're done!

Here's a VBA solution:

```
Sub copyrng()

Dim srcrng As Range
Dim tmprng As Range
Dim dstrng As Range
Dim srcws As Worksheet
Dim dstws As Worksheet



Set srcrng = Application.InputBox("Area to copy", "Source", Type:=8)
Set srcws = srcrng.Parent
Set tmprng = Application.InputBox("Top Left Corner of Destination",  "Destination", Type:=8)
Set dstws = tmprng.Parent
Set dstrng = dstws.Range(tmprng.Address, tmprng.Parent.Cells(tmprng.Row + srcrng.Rows.Count - 1, tmprng.Column + srcrng.Columns.Count - 1))

dstrng = srcrng.Value

 End Sub
```

First answer (answered wrong question)

You can copy visible cells using "Go To..."

Highlight the range you want to copy,  press Ctrl G, click "Special...", select "Visible Cells Only", and then press Ctrl C to copy.

Now all hidden cells will be left behind when you paste.

Comment: I do not think @sql-scholar wants to include the hidden cells when pasting, the bottom screenshot clearly shows that only the visible cells are copied. I understand that he/she only wants to shorten the filtering-selecting-copying-pasting process.

Comment: Sorry, I think I did a lousy job on the screenshot as I should have added an example of *desired way* as the current screenshot shows what currently happens meaning that hidden columns are left behind, however I NEED THEM TO BE INCLUDED!

However, the second part is correct - I was also wondering if it was also possible to automate this filter-copy&paste process, sorry again for making the post a bit messy as I was enquiring about 2 technically different things.

Comment: Other than that. thanks a lot for the feedback. Unfortunately the formula option will not work. They are different Excel files / workbooks and while I am aware that the you can also point a Excel formula to another file, not just another worksheet the problem is that the initial workbook ("Sheet1") will NOT be retained for much longer after the process, meanwhile the other destination worksheet ("Sheet2") will have the log of all the transactions.

Comment: Sounds like it is time for you to dig into VBA.  Good news, you're already using one of the best resources available - stackoverflow!  The code I've provided shows one way to transfer data between sheets.  Use that with answers on how to open, close, and save different workbooks and you should be able to get some helpful code running.  If your workbooks and ranges are always the same or, follow a recognizable pattern, then you can likely create a one button solution.  The best bit if advice I can offer is to look for very specific questions/answers and keep trying until you succeed.

Answer (score 1):

ProfoundlyOblivious code is pretty cool but the

```
dstws = activesheet
```

will always be the source since the activesheet passes back straight after the inputbox.

I tried changing it to

```
Set dstws = tmprng.Parent
```

but for some reason this then breaks the

```
Set dstrng = dstws.Range..
```

I get a Run time error 1004 Method range of object _Worksheet failed?!?!

If I could fix that this solution would work for you with any destination, even other files.

The alternative is to use vba to un-filter the data, then do a copy, then put same filter(s) back on. Once that is done you can go anywhere and paste what is now on the clipboard.

Comment: The problem is that there's more than one bug with my code.  I don't know what I was smoking that day - whatever it was, I don't recommend it!  So yeah, that second 'ActiveSheet` should be `tmprng Parent` like your tried; this creates a problem setting `dstrng` when `tmprng.Parent` is not the `ActiveSheet`.  The source of that problem is the unqualified reference with`Cells(tmprng.Row[...]` because it implicitly references `ActiveSheet` and thus creates an impossible range.  There are two ways to fix.  You can slap an `.Address` at the end of `Cells`, or qualify `Cells` with `tmprng.Parent.`

Comment: Updated my code with qualified references - not sure how I didn't notice all three bugs myself - scary!!   Yes, it will work with other workbook's providing the workbooks are visible to see each other in the same Excel instance. +1 for telling me about my dumb mistake.